# Provide a constructor with Clojure reify

Tags: constructor, clojure, reify

When using [`reify`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/reify) in Clojure, how can I provide an expression for the constructor?

Alternatively, how can I pass arguments to the base class constructor?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot use `reify` to subclass & instantiate classes -- it's only meant for use with protocols and interfaces. (You can provide implementations of methods of `Object`, though.)

To instantiate anonymous subclasses of arbitrary classes and/or interfaces, use `proxy`. All arguments to the superclass ctor of a proxy, if any, go into the `args` vector (the second argument) of the `proxy` form:

```
(proxy [SomeClass SomeInterface-1 ...] [ctor-arg-1 ...]
  ; method impls follow
  ...
  )
```

See `(doc proxy)` for more details.

Comment: Ahh yes, my mistake.  I saw the docs for reify using `Object`, and naively tried to use it on JComponent.  I'll try proxy.